# Pythonic alternative to nested dictionaries and lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I am currently using a dictionary keyed on seconds since epoch combined with a nested dictionary and list to store and look up events.   The strength is that I can quickly look up a value with good performance (think hash).  The weakness is that it is clumsy to search and manipulate the subsequent contents.  I can't help but think my approach is not very Pythonic so I am looking for suggestions.

Here is a simple example using integers rather than seconds since epoch:

```
D = {}

D[1] = {"995" : ["20905", "200101"]}
D[2] = {"991" : ["20901"], "995" : ["20905"]}

eventCode = '995'
error = '90900'

# find entry
if 1 in D:
    # if eventCode exists then append error code
    if D[1][eventCode]:
        D[1][eventCode].append(error)
```

I can look up D[1] quickly, however the remainder of the code doesn't seem very pythonic.  Any suggestions or am I paranoid?

I should check to see if "error" is already in the list.  However, I am unsure how to check for membership in this construct.  This snippet does not work for me:

```
if error not in D[1][eventCode]
```

Comment: Is there a special reason to define D as a `dict` rather than a `list`?

Comment: The last snippet should work fine.

Comment: Does order matter in the lists? If not, consider using sets instead, which have faster lookup & automatic dupe prevention, although sets do consume a little more RAM than lists.

Comment: Order does not matter.  Selcuk - what would a list offer that a dict does not?

Comment: @Selcuk I assume because the times are sparse.  The numbers were changed for the example.

Comment: What happens if the seconds_since_the_epoch or the eventCode aren't in the dictionaries?  Do you add them?

Comment: Mea culpa!  I had a typo in "if error not in D[1][eventCode]".  I bumped off the colon in my haste.  I am intrigued by the use of sets over lists.  RAM should not be an issue (yet)....

Comment: @BrendanAbel - yes, that is the reason I am using a dict.  I can add them as they are reported

Comment: @TomKarzes, that is correct.  It also makes the example easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if that's you want, but you can change lists with [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.5/) to handle duplicates and use [dict.get](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to skip checking if key exists:

```
D = {"995" : {"20905", "200101"}}  # dict: str -> set

# 1) event code not exists, nothing changes:
D.get('111', set()).add('7777')
print(D)  # {'995': {'20905', '200101'}}

# 2) event code exists, error already present, nothing changes:
D.get('995', set()).add('20905')
print(D)  # {'995': {'20905', '200101'}}

# 3) event code exists, error not present, error will be added:
D.get('995', set()).add('7777')
print(D)  # {'995': {'20905', '7777', '200101'}}
```

Comment: To confirm, your suggestion is to combine the dict with sets rather than the lists I am currently using?  D[1] = {"995" : {"20905", "200101"}}

Comment: @Notamachine, if you don't want duplicates in your list and order is not matter, you'd better to use set instead of list.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other suggestions, you could use defaultdict and sets in this way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

D = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict( lambda: None))

D[1] = {"995" : {"20905", "200101"}}
D[2] = {"991" : {"20901"}, "995" : {"20905"}}

eventCode = '995'
error = '90900'

tmp = D[1][eventCode]
if tmp is None:
   D[1][eventCode]={error}
else:
   tmp.add(error)
```

Comment: Both of these answers are excellent.  Let me code them up and see which seems more natural.

Comment: what is the logic behind `(lambda: defaultdict( lambda: None)`?

Comment: @mtk99 what is the preferred method of iterating over a collection?  for k in D.keys() yields the output "6 defaultdict(<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x005C09C0>, {'995': {'90900'}})"

Comment: @Notamachine, don't call .keys, you can iterate over the keys in the dict by just iterating over D, this code is also a round about way of doing http://pastebin.com/XCiVXBGN

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, very nice and tidy!  I assume if D[1] does not exist it will be created and populated?

Comment: @Notamachine, yep, that is the main benefit of using a defaultdict

Comment: @Padraic-cunningham The point was that I didn't want to create sets in every query. Sets are only created when necessary. I like your suggestion but it might lead to additional memory consumption, right?

Comment: @mtk99, the element  gets added to the set if the key exists only if it does not yet exist do you you create a new set,  if it is already in the set then it won't matter as sets don't have dupes and if it is not it just gets added.

Comment: @Padraic-cunningham I am not worried about elements in the set. I understand that. What I am saying is that something like X=D[1]['blabla'] will create a set. You can't check for existence. It does always create a set. Any check consumes memory

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, print (D[1]) yields the same results.  defaultdict(<class 'set'>,{'995': {'20905', '90900'}, '991': {'20901'}}} - which includes an extra "}" as well...

Comment: Your use of lambdas would be way more detrimental than any empty set creation but the point is you are first checking then creating a set anyway, how is setting to None then checking and finally either adding to or creating a new set with an element any different to just adding it?

Comment: @Notamachine, that is completely normal, why do you think there is something wrong?

Comment: @mtk99, you should also try `if 1 in None`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, not concerned, I just want to be sure I can programmatically retrieve the set values for subsequent processing.

Comment: @Notamachine, yes, just access by key or iterate over .items if you want the key/set pairings

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I really like your solution.  The only rub so far is that I would like to be able to refer to the members by name (think objects or JSON) so I can cleanly build feeds using the dict and set data without any iteration.   Still mulling...

Comment: Some of these comments are actually very good answers.  If someone wants to submit them as such I will mark it accepted.